# Program in Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf

Wich is the best way in order to program the creation of this particular square for a ''n'' that we can define in the ambient? In this case n=4.

[image]

Comment: Maybe just use a table. In addition, I would suggest to show more effort.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part [of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 14):

This would have been a good exercise to figure out for yourself, and then you could ask if you got stuck. In general you would probably be better off that way. If you have tried anything, *show us*.  But because there are idiots like me around:

Pretty straight forward, see some comments in the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\N{4} % define your value of N
\foreach [
  % values to be printed along diagonal, save in \i
  evaluate=\n as \i using int(2*\n-1),
  % values printed below the diagonal, save in \j 
  evaluate=\n as \j using int(2*\n), 
]
  \n in {1,...,\N} 
{
% upper left corner of the whole thing is (0,0)
% draw squares along diagonal, with number in the middle
\draw (\n-1,-\n+1) rectangle node{\i} (\n,-\n);
% No lower rectangle for the last value in the loop
% so only draw that if the loop variable is less than \N
\ifnum \n < \N
  \draw (\n-1,-\N) rectangle node{\j} (\n,-\n);
\fi
}
% draw upper and right border
\draw (0,0) -| (\N,-\N);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

This is quite easy using a normal `tabular`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*4{c|}}
\hline
1                  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}                      \\ \cline{1-2}
\multirow{3}{*}{2} & 3                  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\ \cline{2-3}
                   & \multirow{2}{*}{4} & 5         &           \\ \cline{3-4} 
                   &                    & 6         & 7         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

If the number is large, then using TikZ makes sense:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\def\N{7}

\begin{tikzpicture}[sqr/.style={minimum width=1cm,draw},outer sep=0pt]
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as\j using int(2*\i-1), 
             evaluate=\i as\t using int(2*\i)] in {1,...,\N}{
\node(c\j) at (\i,-\i)[sqr,minimum height=1cm, anchor=south]{\j};
\ifnum\i<\N\node at (\i,-\i)[sqr,minimum height=\N cm-\i cm, anchor=north]{\t};
\else\draw(c1.north east) -| (c\j.north east);\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]